# retrieve the row table id when I click the switch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a table view with switch control. My problem is: how can I retrieve the row table id when I click the switch? I can retrieve the switch state but not the id

This is my code to get the state of switch:

```
- (void)aggiungiTag:(id)sender {    
    NSLog(@"the tag value is: %d", [sender isOn]);
    return;
}
```

This is my code to make push switch control into cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    //inseriamo nelle celle la nostra lista
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrTagResidui objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    /*** aggiungo lo switch per i tag ***/
    //lo istanzio e setto la posizione
    UISwitch *switchObj = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 1.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    //setto il valore di default
    switchObj.on = NO;
    //setto l'action ed i controlli degli eventi
    [switchObj addTarget:self action:@selector(aggiungiTag:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
    //aggiungo lo switch alle celle
    cell.accessoryView = switchObj;

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    [arrBoolSwitch insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] atIndex:row]; 
    [switchObj release];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: By the way: You are inserting into arrBoolSwitch every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.  The method may get called multiple times for the same row so you'll end up with more entries in the array than you have rows.  You probably want to alloc it with the right capacity at the start and in cellForRowAtIndexPath just update the NSNumber at the current index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your table, code, etc, etc... but if you're just looking for the row, one option might be to set the `tag` attribute of the `UISwitch` to the indexPath.row (or some value where you can compute that).  Something like:

```
[switchObj setTag:indexPath.row];
```

Then you would have the row id in your method:

```
- (void)aggiungiTag:(id)sender {    
    NSLog(@"the tag value is: %d, row is %d", [sender isOn], [sender tag]);
    return;
}
```

All depends on what the end goal is and what the rest of the app is doing - but it is cheap and easy.

Comment: - (void)aggiungiTag:(id)sender {    
 
 //recupero l'oggetto switch di cui ho bisgno
 UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
 
 //recupero la cella della tabella sulla quale è posizionato lo switch
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview;
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
 
 NSLog(@"the row is: %d", indexPath.row);
 NSLog(@"the tag value is: %d", [theSwitch isOn])

Answer (score 2):

Just tweak your event handler to accept an event parameter:

```
- (void)aggiungiTag:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event {    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:
     [[[event touchesForView:sender] anyObject] locationInView:self.tableView]];
    // do stuff with indexPath
}
```

Don't forget to change the signature in your @selector, too:

```
[switchObj addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(aggiungiTag::) // <-- two colons now :)
    forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that ran! ;)

```
- (void)aggiungiTag:(id)sender {    

    //recupero l'oggetto switch di cui ho bisgno
    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;

    //recupero la cella della tabella sulla quale è posizionato lo switch
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview;
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"the row is: %d", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"the tag value is: %d", [theSwitch isOn])
}
```

Thanks for all!